# QtWebKit gstreamer1.0 not found

Tags: qt, webkit, phantomjs, gstreamer

I want to compile PhantomJS with gstreamer. I downloaded the source code and started the build process with

```
./build.sh --qmake-args WEBKIT_CONFIG+='use_gstreamer'
```

I get the following Error

> Project ERROR: gstreamer-1.0 development package not found

I have an debian 8.0 system with installed libgstreamer1.0 and glib2.0 (installed with apt-get).

Can someone help me?

Comment: How build.sh checks for gstreamer-1.0 presence? Maybe it uses pkg-config?

Comment: good question... how can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed them, you'll need the development packages as well which should be something like `libgstreamer(X.X.X)-dev`, where `X.X.X` is whichever version of `gstreamer` you have installed. The development package has the necessary header files required for compilation.

Comment: The following packages are installed
`libgstreamer1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg is already the newest version.
libgstreamer1.0-dev is already the newest version.`

Answer (score 0):

you may need to modify the build script to add "{GStreamerInstallDir}/1.0/{architecture}/lib/pkgconfig" to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH configuration so cmake can find the package.

Not sure how to do this in your environment as I build on a windows OS where I just specify this using an environment variable from a wrapping batch script.